# Creating jar issue

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

This question may be theoretical but I could not find any proper solution.

Suppose I am making a module which uses 3 jar file(hibernate,log4j,jackson).

Now I want to compile my module and create a jar such that my module can be used by any other module and that module should not require the three jars(hibernate,log4j,jackson) to again.

i.e my module jar file should not have any dependencies.

I am using eclipse.I am able to create a jar(project->export->jar) but it does not include the jars in it
Guide me how can I do that.

Is apache ant of any use here?

Comment: *"Is apache ant of any use here?"*  Theoretically yes.  I mean Ant can get all the classes from each Jar, and make a 'fat' Jar containing them all.  OTOH it is usually a better idea to simply ensure the appropriate Jars are on the run-time class-path.  This is 1) In order to ensure that important information in the manifest of each Jar is retained. 2) To preserve the digital signatures of the original Jars. &.. 3) To avoid legal hassles (most APIs require that you distribute them 'as is'.

Comment: This is what maven and apache ivy solves.  Would that be an option?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:Anything works as long as the tutorial for learning them is small and are easy to use..:-) it will be great if you can provide me with some reference...Do consider m a noob...:-)

Answer (score 1):

**Eclipse's Runnable Jar Wizard**

Eclipse's Runnable Jar Wizard (**File → Export… → Java → Runnable Jar File**) allows developers to create executable jars from an existing run configuration:

[image]

The wizard includes 3 options for handling dependencies:

1. **Extract required libraries into generated jar:** unarchives library
   dependencies and repackages them into your executable jar. This
   option has the advantage of simplicity and does not require a custom
   class loader. However repackaging library jars can cause other
   problems and does not preserve the signatures of signed jars. This
   option may also violate the license terms of the libraries you are
   using.
2. **Package required libraries into generated jar:** creates a "fat jar"
   with a custom class loader. The resultant jar contains
           the application's classes and resources
           library jars required to launch the application
           a small custom class loader that knows how to find jar libraries inside another jar archive
3. **Copy required libraries…:** creates the application archive and copies
   any required library dependencies to the destination folder.

I think the second option suits your present purpose.

Comment: Can you explain what launch configuration is.My jar file doenot have a main function.Its just have helper function and class

Comment: @user2511713: If you doesn't have a main class to use as a launcher than you can consider using some fat jar creation plugins like- JarSplice-http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include all classes from your dependencies into your jar file.
Since a jar file is merely a zip file, you can use any archive manager such as Winzip to explore them, then copy the contents of the jars you depend on into your own jar, taking care to keep the directory structure intact.

That way you have everything in one jar.

Comment: Using a Zip tool to create Jars is very problematic.  Not only do Zip tools support levels of compression that Java does not, but you also have the host of further worries as I outlined in my comment.